# 100% height ie6 compatible

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I need a div (event if it's empty) 100 % the height of the browser and ie6 compatible and working all the time.... any idea or hack.. ? css ?

Comment: Huh? I've never heard of IE6 not understanding `height: 100%;`?

Comment: Is the <div> not 100% of the height inside of another <div>?  If there is something in the <div>, is that content also surrounded in <div> tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, IE6 should support it. Just make sure your DIV's height has something to reference to:

```
#my_div
{
  height: 100%; /* Won't work. What is 100% of an unknown value? */
}
```

Make sure the DIV's parents have a set height. I usually do this (well, not exactly, but you get the idea):

```
#my_div, #parent_of_div, body, html
{
  height: 100%; /* This works, but it will show scrollbars if the body
                   or html elements have padding or margins. */
}
```

I'm not sure what else to say...

Answer (score 0):

If a  has nothing else but other  children, the parent's height will always be 0.  Even if the parent contains a mixture of  tags and other tags, the height will be incorrect.  You must use JavaScript to calculate the height of all the child elements of the  then set the height of the parent .